# Error in Zresolving Resourse file

Tags: android

My Probelm with ANdroid Studio. It cannot resolve the definition of R (Resource file)..
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` ..
 Can anybody help me ?

Comment: If there is a R problem. do clean the project and restart the eclipse it should move off.

Comment: Make sure there is no error in your XML